# What's the more efficient way to create dynamic tags on MeteorJS / Blaze?

Tags: html, meteor, dynamic, tags, meteor-blaze

I'm looking for a solution to manage a HTML tag type with a Reactive Var. I looked all the Blaze documentation but found nothing..

#### Simple example

I want to change a tag from `div` to `form` when a boolean ReactiveVar is updated.

```
Template.MyExample.onCreated(function() {
  this.is_form = new ReactiveVar(false)
})
Template.MyExample.helpers({
  getTag() {
    return Template.instance().is_form.get() ? 'form' : 'div'
  }
})
```

This obviously didn't work:

```
<Template name="MyExample">
  <{{getTag}}>
   
  </{{getTag}}>
</Template>
```

---

#### Nicer solution ?

The "best" way I found to get it was to create a tag template and  list everycase a single time, but I didn't like that solution.

```
Template.MyExample.onCreated(function() {
  this.is_form = new ReactiveVar(false)
})
Template.MyExample.helpers({
  getTag() {
    return Template.instance().is_form.get() ? 'form' : 'div'
  }
})
Template.MyExample.events({
  'click .switch'(e, instance) {
    e.preventDefault()
    instance.is_form.set(!instance.is_form.get())
  }
})
```

Blaze Templates:

```
<Template name="MyExample">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="switch">Switch type</a>
    {{#MyTag tag=getTag}}
      Parent tag is {{getTag}}
    {{/MyTag}}
    {{#MyTag tag="a" attributes=(object href="#" target="_blank")}}
      Link
    {{/MyTag}}
  </div>
</Template>

<Template name="MyTag">
  {{#if equals tag 'form'}}
    <form {{attributes}}>
      {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </form>
  {{else if equals tag 'a'}}
    <a {{attributes}}>
      {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </a>
    <!-- and more and more.... -->
  {{else}}
    <div {{attributes}}>
      {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</Template>
```

Helpers required:

```
Template.registerHelper('object', function({hash}) {
  return hash;
})
Template.registerHelper('equals', function (a, b) {
  return a === b
})
```

This is working but i'm wondering if it's to much for Meteor (and DOM updates). Does this solution works like an simple `{{#if}}...{{/if}}` or it's way heavier ?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you request is basically not supported by Blaze. While static code generators can easily include dynamic tags, this is a very hard one at runtime where you have to deal with the DOM tree, whose element's tag-types are immutable by design.

I first thought of a workaround, that uses child swapping using jQuery in the `onRendered` of `MyTag`:

```js
Template.MyTag.onRendered(function () {
  const instance = this

  instance.autorun(() => {
    const data = Template.currentData()
    const attributes = data.attributes || {}
    const elementName = data.tag
    const refTag = instance.$('.my-tag-ref')
    const newTag = $(`<${elementName}>${refTag.html()}</${elementName}>`)

    Object.keys(attributes).forEach(attKey => newTag.attr(attKey, attributes[ attKey ]))
    newTag.addClass('my-tag-ref')
    refTag.replaceWith(newTag)
  })
})
```

But this is **unfortunately not working**, because the content bock looses it's reactivity and the jQuery instance of the current Template looses it's scope to the root element. I just add it here in case someone catches up on this and finds a solution that works.

Now there is still a solution that works using dynamic Templates:

```html
<Template name="MyTag">
  {{#Template.dynamic template=getTemplate data=getData}}
      {{> Template.contentBlock }}
  {{/Template.dynamic}}
</Template>

<template name="mytaga">
    <a {{attributes}}>
        {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </a>
</template>

<template name="mytagform">
    <form {{attributes}}>
        {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </form>
</template>

<template name="mytagdiv">
    <div {{attributes}}>
        {{> Template.contentBlock }}
    </div>
</template>
```

As you can see the disadvantage is clearly that you have to define lots of new Templates. The advantage is, that you don't have to use so many if/else anymore and it pays out the more often you will have to include `MyTag` in your code.

The respective helpers look like the following:

```js
Template.MyTag.helpers({
  getTemplate() {
    const instance = Template.instance()
    console.log(instance.data)
    return `mytag${instance.data.tag}`
  },
  getData () {
    return Template.instance().data
  }
})
```

> This is working but i'm wondering if it's to much for Meteor (and DOM updates). Does this solution works like an simple {{#if}}...{{/if}} or it's way heavier ?

Blaze is overall slower than for example React or Vue. However, the rendering only updates if the reactive data updates, thus it is just as heavy as the amount of updates to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think your solution just add more complexity on the solution i propose (and i already found it ugly). But like you say its not implemented on Blaze so it'll be good enough.